After fresh install of 24.04 my WinXP & Win10 VBox VMs can't see USB devices
Appears that neither Guest Additions nor Extension Pack are downloaded to the Ubuntu host. Attempts to "insert" the Extension Pack CD from within the VM yields a "Not found. You want to download?" prompt. But download fails with some opaque error related to "certificates".
On Win10 & 22.04 hosts, installing Guest Additions & Extension Pack has always been a routine task. Apparently the process is different for 24.04. What is the process? Is there some other issue that makes USB devices invisible to VBox guests on 24.04? Just trying a simple USB data stick. Nothing esoteric about that. On 22.04 all USB devices except Android tablets, etc. were working.

Is your user account in the vboxusers group? The Extension Pack is installed on the host, not the guest.

That is true and beside the point. The question is: where is the GA ISO? For the 12+ years I've administered VBox VMs hosted on Win & Linux the .ISO had to be downloaded and more recently was staged when VBox was installed/upgraded. That is no longer true on 24.04. Are the GAs and EP now separate packages from VBox on 24.04?

Yes, they are: virtualbox, virtualbox-ext-pack, and virtualbox-guest-additions-iso. And it's the same on Ubuntu 22.04

Thanx. For what it's worth the base package I was directed to was virtualbox-qt. But with the guest additions and ext pack installed, still VMs have ZERO access to USB devices attached to the host. Ordinarily from the VM, Devices->USB shows a list of devces on the host. In my VMs it shows nothing even though at least three USB devices are attached. Devices->USB->USB Settings... is grayed out. Although it shows USB 3.0 selected. Something is out of whack with virtualbox 7.0.16_Ubuntur162802

In all my thrashing with sorting out Guest Additions & Extension Packs and fixing other issues my user name association with vboxusers had gotten obliterated. That's what vboxmanage reported when I listed host USB devices. I had verified that group business when it had been mentioned up front - tail   /etc/group. Once I re-ran usermod, all is good. THANK YOU.
